# Why is the Path I added to zshrc only work when I switch to bash and then switch back?

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, zsh, zshrc

I try to run `conda` in my mac terminal, typing in `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin` clearly worked. However, after I put the path in `.zshrc` and sourced it, it did not work at the first time. Then I switch to `bash` by typing `bash` and then switch back to `zsh`. Then it worked. I am confused by how this happened.

Here are the commands and result I got from terminal:

```
Username: ~ conda --version
zsh: command not found: conda

✘ Username: ~ bash

bash-3.2$ zsh

Username: ~ conda --version
conda 4.3.30
```

My code in `.zshrc` (I add the last line):

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/Username/.oh-my-zsh"

export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: What happens if you initially source your `.zshrc` manually?

Comment: Editing the file alone doesn't update `PATH`; *sourcing* the file (which happens implicitly when you start a new shell) does.

Comment: Running `bash` has nothing to do with it eventually working; running a fresh instance of `zsh` does.